How to position the horizontal axis labels at the bottom low?
How to position the labels (years, in this case) at the very bottom of the cart using Excel Office Scripts?

I've tried this without luck:
chart_3.getAxes().getCategoryAxis().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartAxisPosition.minimum);


Property 'TickLabelPosition' does not exist on type 'Chart'.

Sorry, is that VBA? I'm using Office Scripts


setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartAxisPosition.minimum) doesn't work. I believe it might be a bug.

getAxes().getValueAxis().setPositionAt() is used to change the position of horizontal axis (and labels).

Here's a walkaround solution.


function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let cht = workbook.getActiveChart();
    const min_val = cht.getAxes().getValueAxis().getMinimum();
    cht.getAxes().getValueAxis().setPositionAt(min_val);
}



Fantastic, how did you find this?

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.ChartAxis interface

